# Weird style behavior. Please explain

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I have a style:

```
    <Style TargetType="Image">
        <Setter Property="RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode" Value="HighQuality" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="24" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="24" />
    </Style>
```

It resizes all images inside a panel, as it was intended. However, it doesn't affect images inside DataGrid rows. Why? How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know DataGrid overrides all styles since it applies two different styles of its own, one for editing the cell and one for its normal appearance.